# Laravel 8: Checking user's data with database table does not work properly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have created a two factor authentication system, and it redirects user to `token.blade.php` where he must enters the token that is going to be sent to his phone number and also stored at `active_codes` table.

Now I want to check if the user has entered the same token code that was stored at `active_codes` table which looks like this:

[image]

And then at the Controller, I tried this:

```
public function submit(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->validate([
            'token' => 'required|min:6'
        ]);

        if($data['token'] === auth()->user()->activeCode()->code){
            dd('same');
        }
    }
```

But when I enter the same token, I get this error:

> **ErrorException** Undefined property:
> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::$code

so my question is how to check if the requested token code of user, is as same as the token code which is stored on the DB ?

**Note:** The relationship between `User` and `ActiveCode` Models is OneToMany.

`User.php`:

```
public function activeCode()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ActiveCode::class);
    }
```

`ActiveCode.php`:

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is pretty easy, you are not doing `->first()` or `->get()`, so you are trying to access a model property on a `HasMany` class.

This code should be similar to:

```php
auth()->user()->activeCode()->first()->code
```

But if you have more than 1 code, then you should do something like:

```php
public function submit(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->validate([
        'token' => 'required|min:6'
    ]);

    if(auth()->user()->activeCode()->where('code', $data['token'])->exists()){
        dd('same');
    }
}
```

Comment: What if more that one code exists at the table or user is seeing token blade without logging in.

Comment: If user is at the token blade without logging in, then that is the Route responsibility (use middlewares for that, simple Laravel stuff), and if more than one code exists, then that is why the second option is useful for you, it will look for any existing code associated to that user, if it _exists_ (matches one), it will return `true`.